what should I use now?

confirmTransaction seems deprecated !! what to use now ?
thanks

The current way to handle this
await connection.confirmTransaction({
    blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
    signature: transactionSignature,
  });

So to explain it deeper, you know have to provide the following as an object;
the latest blockhash available,
the last valid block height,
and the signature

thanks for help
I tried with it , still the issue is same
I have posted a new question in detailed , if you have time please see
https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/an-error-occurs-failed-to-post-funding-tx-there-was-id-keep-this-id-conf
