An error occurs: failed to post funding tx - there was id (keep this id!) - Confirmed tx not found
this is repo link I am working with
https://github.com/cryptoloutre/solana-tools/blob/main/src/views/CreateNFTCollectionView/index.tsx
while minitng on devnet got this issue - (❌ Ohoh.. An error occurs: failed to post funding tx - 4qnAxcZQDY6ZxHznNYFqeYNDy6WvLp2r6SZHMBcimt49dguTRJMJZcPdPtcvoT5nfXgRr4uWBC1fxHF9BZWbxGPM (keep this id!) - Confirmed tx not found)
I have checked on solana explore transcation was successful but i ddint got nft in walleet and got this error
I get to know this code using some old deprecated, it should be using
getLatestBlockhash()
and few more deprecated , I am first time working on nft so not much of idea what to do , if someone can please fix this
Any response / help welcome
thanks for time I highly appreciate it

Here is the link to the Transaction
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/4qnAxcZQDY6ZxHznNYFqeYNDy6WvLp2r6SZHMBcimt49dguTRJMJZcPdPtcvoT5nfXgRr4uWBC1fxHF9BZWbxGPM?cluster=devnet
It did work. Not sure why you could it see it.

yes I can see transcation was successful, but I cant see nft in wallet
and also got error Confirmed tx not found
